# Maintaining a scratchpad view state in react-redux

Tags: user-interface, react-redux, state, editing

I'm interested in thoughts on the best way to solve the following problem.  I maintain a state in react-redux, could be anything, a collection of entities for example.  I only update the state if I persist (via API call) or retrieve entities from the server.  I have a form where I can edit the entity prior to persisting it (let's assume this is not a singleton form, but an active form per entity for argument's sake).  Basically the problem I am trying to solve is how to retain a scratchpad copy of the entity in the redux store to be bound to the form components, to be persisted (back to the server and to the store) only when the entire form edit is complete (not bound in the form directly to the store via the state), as each edit would then require a round-trip to the server and it wouldn't be very performant.  Ideas are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Since no-one has replied and I've come up with what I feel is an acceptable solution to the problem.  I'll share it here in case anyone else is looking for the same information.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I decided upon is as follows:

1. Take a copy of a given entity from the redux state and keep it in the local state when editing begins.
2. Editing occurs against the redux state via an entity persistence action.  This way the redux state is always up to date.
3. If editing is aborted, the copy gets persisted back to the redux state.
4. Once editing is complete an async action is dispatched to persist the entity.  View state is already up to date.

This seems to work for me.